# How to make scroll of a webView faster and smoother in android

Tags: android

Hi I am loading a pdf from server to my web view using docs.google.com

```
mWebview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&url=+MY URL");
```

and its loading and working fine but the scroll is not smooth and fast. how can I improve it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

why not let the browser open the same link? The browser performs much better than a WebView. And of course, you can simply navigate back to your app using the back button

Comment: Thanks first, Its a pdf file and it should open from my application by clicking a link, some header and footer images also I need to add for this screen so loading in webview

Comment: is your web view inside a scroll view by any chance?